# How to generate a simplified mini line chart?

Tags: visualization

I would like to create an extremely simplified line chart that minimizes space usage while efficiently conveying the trends and variations in the data.
Therefore, I expect this line chart to exclude components such as axes, labels, and legends, focusing solely on the line segments.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question will obviously vary widely whether you want to draw such a small graph in JavaScript, R, Excel or whatever software you favour.

It may be best to provide you with the search term "sparkline". See https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Sparkline for examples and then search it together with your plot creating software of choice.